# I am trying to start a robotics club

Tags: turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am an IT guy.  I have a 2 year degree in web design and computer networking.  So I know C++ ,HTML, CSS, and PHP.  When I found out that robots use the C++ I almost fell out of my chair.  So I am trying to start a robotics club in NC.  I have not been able to find robotics clubs in NC.  Do you have any suggestion's?  What is the hardest part of robotics?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206261/i-am-trying-to-start-a-robotics-club./) by [hallman](https://answers.ros.org/users/22026/hallman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2015-03-30

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2015-08-12**:
why you almost fell out of your chair? is that so surprising?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The biggest upfront challenge is getting enough equipment available for a club to work on.  A TurtleBot is excellent.  I'd also recommend getting an Arduino.  You can experiment with OpenCV with just a standard webcam.

---

Originally posted by [Mark Silliman](https://answers.ros.org/users/20282/mark-silliman/) with karma: 81 on 2015-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Alternatively, you could also look into simulators such as [Gazebo](http://wiki.ros.org/gazebo_ros_pkgs) or [v-rep](http://www.coppeliarobotics.com/index.html). This has the advantage that you can try out robots that are otherwise to expensive to get at for a robotics club and only available to academia/industry.

You could also look around for 3D printed robots. These are usually cheap. For example, look at this [indiegogo project](https://www.indiegogo.com/projects/learn-3d-printed-robotics-makerclub).

---

Originally posted by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) with karma: 529 on 2015-04-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lukewd](https://answers.ros.org/users/37399/lukewd/) on 2018-09-10**:
I would add that a 3d printer is not a bad investment, you can make a ton of cheap different types of robots w/ a 3d printer.  We're going on our third year using mostly 3d printed robots for a robotics class at my kids' school and it has worked out really well.  Costs 2-4 dollars each in plastic.